# What is the function of Twitter's verify credentials API?

Tags: api, rest, oauth, twitter

I just implemented [sign in with twitter](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Sign-in-with-Twitter) for my webapp. At the end of the OAuth 3-legged flow, I needed to retrieve the screenname & avatar pic for the user. All I had was the twitterid e.g. 3546735

So I performed a GET http://twitter.com/users/show/3546735.json
No security is required for this method, although it is rate-limited.

Recently I've read about another api method called [verify credentials](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-account%C2%A0verify_credentials)

Why should I call this compared to the simple GET above ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's of little use to you since you're already doing OAuth. It would provide the credentials in a single request, which can be easier to implement in some applications. Stick with OAuth if you've already done the work.

Answer (score 1):

One use of `account/verify_credentials` for OAuth is it gets the logged in users profile information without affecting the rate limit.

**Update**: verify_credentials now counts against the users rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the verify credentials approach is being phased out. OAuth seems to be the preferred approach.

Answer (score 0):

I felt the need to reply to this and contribute since I've been working and have struggled with the twitter oauth api.

in short verify credentials returns the authenticating users' profile given their access token and token secret.

the reason for this is because in oauth 1.0a flow; after the user completes authentication, twitter sends an oauth_verifier token to you which is used to exchange request tokens for access and token secrets. At this point you do not know the user but have their credentials(access token and token secret). You can verify credentials to identify the owner of these tokens.